# How to store a TB size C++ array on a cluster

Tags: c++, memory-management, heap-memory, large-data, hpc

I want to do a huge simulation that requires ~ 1 TB of data to describe a bunch of interacting particles (each has different interactions). Is it possible to store this data in a C++ array?

I have access to a 60 node cluster. Each node has 2 CPUs with 48x16GB DDR4. So that's a total of 192 GB per node, or 11520 GB = 11 TB total RAM on the cluster. How would you dynamically allocate a 1 TB array on this cluster?

Comment: from the C++ perspective a 1 TB array is theoretically not a problem. Assuming the smallest element size (1 byte) the size required is ~`1e+12` which is within the range of `size_t` on x86 ~`1.8e19`. So the ball is on the cluster side. What virtualization does it use, what OS and what underlying distributed system it uses for sharing the RAM.

Comment: @bolov: 1 TB of data consumes 1 TB of address space no matter how large each element is (see: "How much does a pound of feathers weigh?").  And the address space on x86_64 is nowhere near 1.8e19 bytes, in fact it is far, far less than that due to hardware limitations (48 bit addresses, 2.8e14 addressable bytes).

Comment: @JohnZwinck my analysis was about if the size of the array can be stored (in `size_t`). As for the address space, there are virtualization and ds systems that allow you to access that much ram for a single process, even if it is distributed over server nodes.

Comment: How do you come to the figure of 192GB per node? 48 lots of 16GB is 768GB

Answer (score 0):

You have 1 TB of data and 11 TB total memory.  It is therefore no problem to store all your data on your cluster, it's just a question of how.

You could pack it onto as few nodes as possible, which is six nodes.  Or you could spread it out onto all 60 nodes.  Which approach is better depends on many things, including the access patterns with which you will use this data, the cost model of your cluster (is it free no matter how many nodes you use?), and more.

You need to identify what is the maximum memory usable by each single task on your particular cluster.  This is something configured by the cluster administrators.  For example some clusters may evenly divide the memory so the 192 GB RAM in each node might only be available if you run one task for core on the node, not if you run one task per node.  You haven't told us how many cores there are, and obviously we have no idea what your cluster's usage policies are.

The answer to your C++ question is: Yes, you can store 1 TB in a C++ `vector` or `array` or `list` or `map` or any other data structure.  C++ imposes no limitations here.